# Dealing with compilation times when editing headers

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a huge project which uses a system that, when running make, generates some header files that contain some constants that are used everywhere in the code. Due to the size of this project if one of those headers is changed (a constant is removed or another is added) almost the whole project must be recompiled (which sometimes takes several hours).

My initial solution was to write some sort of `ConstantManager` class that has a map with each code-value pair and a getter that returns that given the code as a string returns its value (pretty straight forward) and also change the header generator so it would define the constants as `#define`s that expand to an instance of the `ConstantManager` and a call to the getter. The problem with this is that it will not work with `switch` statements (well... `case` statements actually) because the return values are not constant expressions.

My question is: are there any alternative solutions to this problem or some trick to make mine work with switches?

Comment: You can provide functions that return the constant values, and have the header that changes only be used by that source. Nothing will help with switches though, they need direct constants.

Comment: Do you absolutely need those number as constant? How about load them at runtime. with the switch-case issue, using a loop with test function seems more fit.

Comment: @Calvin: I don't need them as constants, the 15 583 switches that use them require that and I'm sure as hell not going to manually change them to if/else ifs

Comment: Are `constexpr` not usable in switch-case statements?

Comment: @RedX: yes, they are, but how will that help with me problem?

Comment: @user1233963 how the `constexpr` would help in your problem?, I think that [this example](http://ideone.com/5jZ9Kr) could try to answer that question.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster He still needs to recompile, since a header was touched.

Comment: @BЈовић no recompilation is needed if all the values are placed in a `cpp` file while all the getters were still in the `h`; but there's no way to avoid recompilation while adding or removing constants though; I've only focused my comment on the "cannot-use-constexpr-in-switch" part :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the huge header into smaller ones and include those. This might be a lot of initial work but is the most straight forward and probably compatible with your current solution.

Another option is to create to make your ConstManager class have constexpr members. For this you would not need much but you cannot use map.

**ConstManager.h**

```
namespace ConstManager {

  namespace detail {
    struct Constant {
      char const * const name;
      char const * const value;
    };


    Constant const * const constants;
    unsigned int total_variables;
  }

  inline char const * const ConstManager::get(char const * needle) constexpr {
    using namespace ConstManager::detail;
    /* i was not able to quickly find a constexpr compatible binary search function*/
    if(int i = 0;  i < total_variables; ++i){
      Constant & const c = constants[i];
      if(strcmp(c.name, needle) == 0){
        return c.value;
      }
    }
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

**ConstManager.c** should be generated

```
ConstManager::detail::Constant ConstManager::detail::constants [] = {
  {"first var", "first value"},
  {"second var", "second value"}
};

unsigned int ConstManager::detail::total_variables = 2;
```

---

First solution proposed (this was before the first edit):

I think you should replace all your defines by regular external variables.

Although two caveats:

1. It will not work if those defines are used to concatenate strings
2. It might make inlining harder if not impossible for the compiler but if this matters only a profiler can tell.

**constmgr.h**

```
  // make all your needed constansts externs
  namespace Constants {
    extern int const theFirstConstant;
    extern char const * const someStringConstant;
  }
```

And the source file is then generated at build time.

**constexpr.cpp**

```
 int const Constants::theFirstConstant = 1000;
 char const * const Constants::someStringConstant = "hihihoho";
```

Comment: This will not work if I remove/add a new constant ( I should have mentioned this in the question, sorry )

Comment: Why would this not work if you remove or add variables? In that case the header is changes and the dependencies are updated. Maybe you can split the constmgr header into smaller headers and only include those.

Comment: @user1233963 This solution is intended for changing values. Not for changing/adding of new variables.

Comment: Because that constmgr.h will have changed and any other file that include it will need recompilation